# Pre-defined Table vs Java-defined Table on Android's SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm well aware that this question might be not suitable for this site. I've tried to google this but i can't find the answer i'm looking for.

I was wandering, which one is better : The pre-defined SQLite table (ex : using SQLite manager to create table) or java-defined table (create the table on the java code)?

Which one is faster? which one is more secure?

Please kindly share your knowledge, Thanks for your time :D

**UPDATE**

Sorry to confuse you, what i mean by java-defined table is you run the SQL query on the java code, so the table will be created on the runtime.

Code example (taken from vogella) :

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";
```

Comment: What do You mean by java-defined table? Arrays?

Comment: And by SQLite manager You mean 3rd party software to manage a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't work with database in assets(You call it pre-defined table) but I remember reading that this method it worth effort only if You have database with lots of data on installation.

If You have small database [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) makes it really easy to work with db in android.

Database is created/updated only on installation/update of application so You don't have to worry about optimization so much.